# cannot get c program to build, compiler doesn't find include files

Tags: c, include

When attempting to compile a c program it never finds the include files. In a program located in ~/hbc/channel (offending file is in ~/hbc/channel/channelapp/source/xml.c) I get the following error:

```
source/xml.c:8:18: fatal error: mxml.h: No such file or directory
```

my PATH is set as follows:

```
dan@htpc~/hbc/channel-$ export | grep DEVKIT
declare -x DEVKITARM="/home/dan/devkitpro/devkitARM"
declare -x DEVKITPPC="/home/dan/devkitpro/devkitPPC"
declare -x DEVKITPRO="/home/dan/devkitpro"
```

And the file is there with the include files in the devkit:

```
dan@htpc~/hbc/channel-$ find ~/ | grep mxml.h
/home/dan/devkitpro/devkitPPC/include/mxml.h
```

Since it would be insane to have to edit every single file to point to its required library or header, I really need to ask.

Is there something I'm missing out? How can I set these paths properly so that the compiler sees them? I couldn't find anything else regarding this question and the development environment is set correctly since I could compile simpler code. It's this code requiring external libraries that's failing to find them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would the environment variables have any effect on the compilation?  You have to tell the compiler where the header is; it won't use the environment variables to find them.

Comment: You use `-I${DEVKITPPC}/include` on the C compiler command line — but that is the compiler using the result of your shell or `make` converting a reference to an environment variable into a string; it is not the compiler making use of the environment variable directly.  Now `#include "mxml.h"` will probably find `/home/dan/devkitpro/devkitPPC/include/mxml.h` for you.

Comment: Is the difference between `/home/dan/devkitpro/devkitPPC` and `/home/dan/devkitpro/devkitPPC/include` relevant? Looks like another folder hierarchy is missing.